# Android, Element of my custom ListView not visible

Tags: android, listview, visible

I try to create a simple ListView with CustomAdapter, but the ListView doesn't display any element. I tried to change the background color and it change correctly... So it's not the ListView who's not display, but the elements I think.

Any help would be nice, I've searched for hours what's the problem...

There is my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblNFC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblNFC_text" />

        <!-- Read Only -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextNFC"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="Click scan to search NFC"
            android:inputType="none" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFindNFC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
            android:text="@string/btnFindNFC_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item_var.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/var"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif" >
            </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<VarDetails> _data;
    Context _c;

    CustomAdapter(ArrayList<VarDetails> data, Context c) {
        _data = data;
        _c = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) _c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_var, null);
        }

        TextView varView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.var);
        TextView valueView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);

        VarDetails var = _data.get(position);
        varView.setText(var.var);
        valueView.setText("Value: " + var.value);

        return v;
    }

}
```

VarActivity.java

```
public class VarActivity extends Activity {
    ListView varList;
    ArrayList<VarDetails> details;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        varList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        details = new ArrayList<VarDetails>();

        VarDetails Detail;

        Detail = new VarDetails();
        Detail.setVar("Var1");
        Detail.setValue("Value1");
        details.add(Detail);

        Detail = new VarDetails();
        Detail.setVar("Var2");
        Detail.setValue("Value2");
        details.add(Detail);

        Detail = new VarDetails();
        Detail.setVar("Var3");
        Detail.setValue("Value3");
        details.add(Detail);

        varList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(details, this));
    }
}
```

VarDetails.java

```
public class VarDetails {

    String var;
    String value;

    public String getVar() {
        return var;
    }

    public void setVar(String var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think your ArrayList  `_data` is null, as you haven't instantiate it. What happen when you set `Match parent` as height of `listView`

Comment: why android:layout_height="0dip"?

Comment: if I set Match_parent as height, eclipse just warns me that 0dp is better for performance.
But the ListView isn't displayed as well...

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you should bind the data of VarDetail with the layout elements within your custom adapter

after

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_var, null);
```

you could try for example

```
TextView varView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.var);
varView.setText(_data.get(position).getVar());
```

Comment: Thx for your help, I tried what you said, but the elements of the listView are still not displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your LinearLayout in list_item_var.xml. The orientation is horizontal, all your child text views have layout_width="match_parent", so the text view will get pushed out of view because the first has expand on all the width space. Try set them to "wrap_content". Also set layout_weight if your textview has different proportions.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not change anything... :(

Comment: Ok, can't promise they'll work, but try these suggestions:
1) remove the middleman variable "v" in your getView(). Directly use convertView and return convertView instead.
2) In your getView() Change vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_var, null) to inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_var, parent,false)

Comment: Also, declare your strings var and value as public, or use method getVar() and getValue() to retrieve their values instead of var.var

Comment: Thx for your help. I tried what you suggest but the problem isn't solved.. my listView isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

change list_item_var.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/var"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```